# How to run 2 methods at the same time?

Tags: c#, coroutine

I have tried using system.threading.task.task.factor.startnew but it still pauses the whole thing.

```
using System;

namespace test
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void test2 ()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }

    public static void Update ()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        Console.WriteLine("testt");
    }


    public static void Main ()
    {
        while (true) {
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew (() => test2 ());
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew (() => Update ());
        }
    }

}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to do? does test2 need to be invoked (called) by Update?  do they need to start up at the same time?  have you looked into using threads?

Comment: Task2 needs to be called by update and they do not need to start up at the same time. Ive tried using threads but there is very little info on them.

Comment: on the contrary there is plenty of info on starting up threads.  google/bing c# thread, task, tpl, delegate.  on a side note, i find it funny this was closed as duplicate referencing a question that was put on hold...go figure  :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two threads

```
 class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(MainClass.test2);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(MainClass.Update);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void test2()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("Test");

            }
        }

        public static void Update()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: Got this error: The name 'task' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Fixed it by changing Task.Factory.StartNew to System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew.